# Find the number of pairs of vectors $\vec V_1 =a_1 i +b_1j + c_1k$ and $\vec V_2=a_2i+b_2j+c_2k$ such that $V_1,V_2$ are perpendicular

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Find the number of pairs of vectors $\vec V_1 =a_1 i +b_1j + c_1k$ and $\vec V_2=a_2i+b_2j+c_2k$ such that $V_1,V_2$ are perpendicular  where all $a,b,c \in\{-2,-1,1,2\}$

From given info
$$a_1a_2 + b_1b_2 + c_1c_2=0$$

Nowwe can have the following cases
$$+4+2+2$$
$$+4-2-2$$
$$-2+1+1$$
$$+2-1-1$$

I am having trouble finding the number of possible arrangements after this because

1)+4-2-2 and others can interchange in among themselves

2)there are multiple ways to obtain product 4, -2, etc.

All this is getting really cumbersome to calculate. How can I simplify this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i) $a_1a_2 = 4, b_1b_2 = c_1c_2 = -2$

$\begin{matrix} i & j & k \\ 2 & -2 & -2 \\ 2 & 1 & 1\end {matrix}$

- There are four ways to assign negative sign to column $j$ and $k$ - top row negative, bottom row negative, one of the diagonals negative
- There are two ways for $j$ and $k$ pair - same digits pairs and different digit pairs.

$\begin{matrix} j & k \\ -2 & -2 \\ 1 & 1\end {matrix} \ $
and
$ \ \begin{matrix} j & k \\ -2 & 1 \\ 1 & -2\end {matrix}$

- First column $(2,2)$ pair can be $i, j $ or $k$ pair.
- Also we can have $(-2, -2)$ instead of $(2, 2)$

That gives us $4 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 48$ possible pairs.

*$a_1a_2 = -4, b_1b_2 = c_1c_2 = 2$ will give us same number of pairs.*

ii) $a_1a_2 = 2, b_1b_2 = c_1c_2 = -1$

$\begin{matrix} i & j & k \\ 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & -1\end {matrix}$

Again, there are four ways to assign negative sign. $(2,1)$ i-pair can be $i, j $ or $k$ pair. First column pair $(2, 1)$ can also be $(-2, -1)$. But in this case, $j$ and $k$ have same digits $(1, 1)$.

That gives us $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 24$ possible pairs.

*$a_1a_2 = -2, b_1b_2 = c_1c_2 = 1$ will give us the same number of pairs.*

So total number of unordered pairs $ = 2 \cdot 48 + 2 \cdot 24 = 144$.

Now if $V_1$ and $V_2$ are ordered, it will lead to $288$ pairs.

Comment: But the ans is 288

Comment: Also i didn’t understand how you arranged to get 3.2.2

Comment: @Aditya apologies. I had a mistake. Fixed it and yes the answer is $288$.

Comment: How do we know we aren’t overcounting cases

Comment: Because we are working case by case and only counting unique pairs. Also you had a question on how we get $3 \cdot 4 \cdot 2$. Is that clear or should I explain?

Comment: I think I got it, but I would love it if you do explain it, in case I got it wrong

Comment: I added more details and I also rearranged cases. See if this helps. To be honest with you, I got mixed up couple of times myself while answering this. But I am confident of my answer now.

Comment: So the reasoning for getting 3 was basically 3!/2! right?

Comment: @Aditya yes that is correct.

Comment: Understood, thanks a lot!