How many pairs of vectors in $\{\pm1,\pm2\}^3$ are perpendicular?
The problem goes as follows:

How many pairs of vectors $$V_1 = a_1i+b_2j+c_1k\\ V_2 = a_2i+b_2j+c_2k$$ are there such that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are mutually perpendicular and $$a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2\in\{-2,-1,1,2\}?$$

I tried to solve this by making pairs, I know that $V_1\cdot V_2 = 0$ for orthogonal vectors which corresponds to $$a_1a_2 + b_1b_2 + c_1c_2 = 0$$
The products $\{a_1a_2, b_1b_2, c_1c_2\}$ that could satisfy this equation are {-4,2,2} , {4,-2,-2}, {2,-1,-1} and {-2,1,1} (and other permutations of these).
I tried to fix the value of $a_1a_2 = \{-2,2,4,-4\}$ thus fixing all the other values, so there are $4$ possibilities for $a_1$ and that leaves us with $2$ for others
I tried to take individual cases but my answers don't match any of the given options

Welcome to MSE. I don't quite understand your attempt. I've edited it slightly. Please check if that is what you mean

Can you please edit your post to include the details of your "and that leaves us with 2
for others", and "the given options"?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4191478/find-the-number-of-pairs-of-vectors-vec-v-1-a-1-i-b-1j-c-1k-and-vec-v-2?rq=1

@mathophile Thanks
